# How to output JSON with swig in nodejs

Tags: node.js, swig-template

I tried json filter, but I get "json" filter not found error. What I'm I doing wrong?

```
Error: Filter "json" not found at Object.exports.wrapFilter (......./node_modules/swig/lib/helpers.js:310:11)
<script type="text/javascript">
        {{ places|json }}
</script>
```

object is passed from mongodb

```
this.displayMainPage = function(req, res, next) {
    "use strict";

    places.getPlaces(10, function(err, results) {
        "use strict";

        if (err) return next(err);

        return res.render('places_template', {
            places: results
        });
    });
}
```

Edit: I'm trying to output json to pass to google maps and display the same data in html

Comment: What version of Swig do you have installed? The `helpers.js` the error mentions isn't used in recent versions of the library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For versions of Swig prior to 1.0, the [`json` filter](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/filters/#json) was instead named [`json_encode`](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/blob/v0.14.0/lib/filters.js#L133-L135):

```
{{ places|json_encode }}
```

And, for compatibility, 1.0 and later keep `json_encode` [as an alias](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/blob/v1.0.0/lib/filters.js#L247) of `json`.

---

Though, you should also consider upgrading Swig:

```
$ npm install swig@0.14
npm WARN deprecated swig@0.14.0: v1.0.0 is a complete rewrite of Swig
from the ground up. Previous versions are no longer supported
```

Comment: thank you, upgrading swig fixed the error, but I get json with &quot. ` [{&quot;_id&quot;:&quot;52895b73ab025fe9ce4b980c&quot;,&quot;address1&quot;:&quot;Boerum Pl. &amp; Schermenhorn Street&quot;,&quot;address2&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;city&quot;:&quot;Brooklyn&quot;,&quot;lat&quot;:40.6903327,&quot;lng&quot;:-73.9896449,` How do I remove them?

Comment: @VladVinnikov You can use [`{% autoescape false %}`](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/tags/#autoescape) to disable HTML encoding.

Comment: I prefer to not disable autoescaping for all filters, only for this case you can use filter "raw":        `{{ places|raw|json_encode }}`

Comment: `|raw` should be part of the main answer. Thanks @Krayton